# How to access a dictionary key inside a string

Tags: python, string, api, dictionary

I have an API that expects to receive the data in a string format. The data looks like this:

```
test = """{"API_name":"getScenario","token":"1112223333","clientId":"1","clientEmail":"yup@nope@gmail.com", "more": "hello"}"""
```

I am used to accessing the dictionary keys rather easily `test[token]` but in this case it is all encased in a multi-line string.

How is this supposed to be accessed?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend reading about JSON.

Comment: is your "string" valid json? If so, treat it like json...

Comment: There is no reason to downvote the question - lighten up a bit. It was unclear that it this was JSON which simply needed to be parsed. Everytime I have accessed JSON it was not a multi-line quote around the JSON data.

If I knew everything I would not be here asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the string and then find access by key

```
import json
data = json.loads(test)
data['API_name']
```

Comment: I knew it was json format but didn't know I needed to parse! Thank you!